# Updating to google play services 11.2.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is it possible  update to google play services 11.2.0  and use the corresponding features of Google Places API while using API LEVEL 25(Nougat)? or do i have to use a targetSDK version of 26

Answer (score 0):

You must target version 26 whenever upgrading Google Play Services to 11.2.0 and onwards. This is clearly stated in the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases):

> When you upgrade your app’s Play services dependencies to 11.2.0 or
>   later, your app’s build.gradle must also be updated to specify a
>   compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O).